# c# Photoshop CS5 Scripting

Tags: c#, scripting, dialog, photoshop, flash-cs5

I have created a c# windows service which automates photoshop to perform image manipulation but even though I have specified :

`psApp.DisplayDialogs = PsDialogModes.psDisplayNoDialogs;`

and

`psApp.NotifiersEnabled = false;`

Some dialogs are still getting displayed!

For example, if an image is corrupted or was created in an older version of photoshop it displays a dialog which needs to be dismissed to continue.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me please?

Comment: Probably the same as with Office: The automation works for some simple cases but isn't really useful or intended for reliable non-interactive tasks.

Comment: yeah to be honest its starting to look like that, thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with this before (in CS2). Have you tried this before opening an image?

```
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice but CS5 seems to ignore this flag - I'm closing this question because I'm sure there is no answer :(